# How to add weights to Textview in Gridview programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-gridview

I have a GirdView of 9 TextViews. I want to make the 9 Textviews to distribute equally in the height and the width. to fit the GridView exactly. How can I do this?

This is how I add Textviews to Gridview

```
String[] arrayEmpty = new String[] {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arrayEmpty));
gridView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,list));
```

This is what I have got
 [image]

I tried to use something like `gridview.layoutparams` but I could not. Help me to distribute them equally like this 
[image]

I have overrided the method onMeasure, but did not work

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class myGridView extends GridView {
public myGridView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public myGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public myGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
}

}
```

Comment: @PankajKumar can you explain more please?

Comment: Check out my Question again, this is what I have did but still getting exception @PankajKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

[Git Hub](https://github.com/romario333/opensudoku/tree/master/OpenSudoku).

It's open source project in Git Hub.Here you can find layout and source code for Sudoku.I hope it will help you.

Comment: could you give a specific answer, it is a big project to inspect each class or layout

Comment: @Abd El-Rahman El-Tamawy check it.I have edited my answer.

Comment: I have checked it, still confused. The first project is so huge to find similar code and the second on is not in Java

Comment: @Abd El-Rahman El-Tamawy-wait..I will see if i find some useful for u.

Comment: @Abd El-Rahman El-Tamawy-Check in the project link that i have posted above res/layout/sudoku_edit.xml for Sudoku View.

Comment: I have found out that the trick is in overriding the method onMeasure for the class that extend GridView, but what I should do exactly. I don`t know....i Tried to but the hight and the width same as each other but it did not works

Comment: thank you for your help, but still have the same problem

Comment: @Abd El-Rahman El-Tamawy-I have not implemented sudoku yet so i have suggested you links..but i will try to find some more useful links only for you.